# How can I test payments on Bigcommerce store with PayPal sandbox?

Tags: bigcommerce

I have read a pile of dox on PP sandbox testing but caanot understand the final stage of this process.
I have PayPal Express CHeckout installed on my Bigcommerce store.
I have valid PP business account.

I signed in to PP developer site using my live PP credentials, created 1 seller test account and 1 buyer test account. I can edit settings in both of them.

And the main question is how I can make sure that MY LIVE STORE payments work well using this PP sandbox?

I go to my web store, put a product into the cart, go to checkout and see PP page which is NOT related to the PP test sandbox page in any way. PP offers me to make a real payment.

How can I test it?
Thanks.

Comment: This would be a question better for our support team. Toll free US #: 888-699-8911

Comment: I have just spent half an hour with BC support - feature to switch PP to sandbox test mode is available only to BC developers or partners statuses.
If you set up you store and are neither of the two you cannot test.

Such a strange limitation.
What I need is shown here, for Woocommerce: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YkunOqCMiWc
But unfortunately not for BC.